# Ubuntu, openSUSE, Fedora and Elementary all fail to do acpi tasks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, opensuse, acpi

When I close the laptop lid, when I want to shutdown, restart or halt my system always freezes. Only Windows has no problems with these tasks. What may be the cause?
The BIOS doesn't provide any options regarding this problem so I doubt that this might be it.

It worked before on Ubuntu but it doesn't now.

My Laptop is a HP 250-G3 with no hardware changes at all.

Comment: Does you laptop shuts down correctly with `sudo shutdown now`? Anything to see if you switch to tty1 (Alt-Ctrl-F1, assuming you can)?

Comment: It completely freezes. Not even SysRq+REISUB does anything.

Comment: So, check the contrent of /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages, they may show what was the last thing  happening during shutdown.